# How add dark gradient on bottom of an image in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am creating a banner where we are showing some text on top of an image. The Text is a bit difficult to read due to background Image so Can I make the background darker where the text is present ?

Comment: The idea is to use an dark overlay, you think in layers, the last layer is the image, next is the dark overlay container, then it's the text you want, if I could I'd ve written some code so I'm so sorry for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient)

```js
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient"

<ImageBackground
    style={{width : '100%', height: 280}}
    source={{uri : "image_url"}}>

    <LinearGradient 
        colors={['#00000000', '#000000']} 
        style={{height : '100%', width : '100%'}}>



    </LinearGradient>

</ImageBackground>
```

the result

[image]

#### update

as @codeSays404 comment, for `expo` use [expo-linear-gradient](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/).
just replace this line in the code above.

```js
//replace this
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient"
//with
import LinearGradient from "expo-linear-gradient"
```

Comment: Thanks worked as expected. I was using expo so had to use a different package for gradient.

Answer (score 0):

So you can achieve that by having a text container with backgroundColor to be of suppose 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)' .

Eg

```
<Image>
<View style={{
position:'absolute',
zIndex:2
backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
bottom:0
}} >
<Text>Hey</Text>
</View>
</Image>
```

Do let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [ImageBackground](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground) component? An easy solution would be to configure the backgroundColor of the text. It is possible to set it to an RGBA value. Try setting it to `backgroundColor: "#00000060"`. You can check out the example on the ImageBackground page.

If you dont like the rectangular shape you can add `borderRadius: 200` to create rounded edges.

Comment: I wasn't using Image Background. Now I changes that as per above answer and its working